1st Party Cookie returning Undefined in GTM
New to GTM and here, can anyone suggest why GTM might not be capturing cookie info even after consent?


Is the cookie there when the container is loaded or is the cookie dropped after the fact?

So I figured it's rather impossible to capture that unless the person visiting the website has filled a form or given the info beforehand at a certain moment before.

Is this an HTTP-only Cookie? In this case, it can only be read by a server in first-party-context, not via JavaScript (as GTM does). You can check for HTTP-only in the developer-tool's cookie list.
